# Initialize numpy array using in-place sorted list

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, in-place

I'm observing some odd behavior.  Here is the snippet of code:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = [[1, .3], [0, .5], [2, .23]]
>>> b = np.array(a.sort())
>>> b
array(None, dtype=object)
```

Is this behavior expected?  If I add an intermediate step for the in-place sort, it works as expected:

```
>>> a = [[1, .3], [0, .5], [2, .23]]
>>> a.sort()
>>> b = np.array(a)
>>> b
array([[ 0.  ,  0.5 ],
       [ 1.  ,  0.3 ],
       [ 2.  ,  0.23]])
```

Can someone explain what is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `a.sort()` does not return the sorted list. It returns `None`:

```
>>> a.sort() is None
True
```

You could use `sorted(a)`:

```
>>> b = np.array(sorted(a))
>>> b
array([[ 0.  ,  0.5 ],
       [ 1.  ,  0.3 ],
       [ 2.  ,  0.23]])
```

However, this would create a (sorted) copy of `a`.

Comment: Or alternatively, `b = np.sort(a)` if you want to use numpy's `sort` rather than the Python builtin